# What names does CMake reserve?

Tags: cmake, reserved-words

I am creating a library, where all components are independent (it's only because it's easier to manage 1 git repo, really).
In that library's root folder, I have 1 sub-folder for each part of the library's components, with exactly 3 "interesting folders" (src,tests,include/components_name). I have hardcoded those folders in a foreach loop so that all actions will be done for all modules by default.

The problem seems to be that, one of the modules is named "option_parser" which is, indeed, relatively generic, and also seems to be "reserved" by cmake, and same for everything derived from it. I've tried "option_parser_test", "option_parser_tests", and other random names based on "option_parser_" root.

Where I can learn how to avoid names that cmake reserves?
And how can I affect them anyway to my binaries (because, I feel like it's stupid to change a project's name because of a build system. Might be a strong enough reason to switch it.)

Comment: `seems to be "reserved" by cmake` - Which error/warning make you think, that `option_parser` module is reserved? And what to you mean by "module"? Do you mean script `<name>.cmake` which may be included with `include(<name>)` command? Or what?

Comment: Let's say my git repo is $HOME/foobar. In it, there would be some folders named, for example, option_parser, unique_res, and dyn_array. Each is a standalone library, but I would like to compile all (for now) of them into a single library binary (shared or not, it's not important here) through cmake. Their structure is always the same: ./tests, ./include/$(pwd) and ./src. So I call them modules. The exact error is "  The target name "./option_parser" is reserved or not valid for certain CMake features, such as generator expressions, and may result in undefined behavior."

Comment: So, it is not a *module name* `option_parser`, but a **target name** `./option_parser` which is reserved, isn't it? Simply do not use *target name* which contains a dot (`.)`. Normally, target name should be an **identificator**, which contains no punctuation and other special characters.

Comment: Yes, sorry for bad denomination. And oops, I didn't noticed the "./"... but I suppose my question remain valid: where is the information about what makes correct target names?

Comment: Yes, the question about reserved **target names** is still *valid*. But it is better to **edit the question post** accordingly: Add exact error message into it, and a code (in minimal form) which cause that message.

Answer (score 3):

It's really quite simple. Use these three commands to see all reserved words:

```
cmake --help-command-list
cmake --help-variable-list
cmake --help-property-list
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635230) of [Cinder Biscuits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3957200/cinder-biscuits) above should probably already help you.

Additionally, you should probably read CMake's own [documentation regarding the CMake language](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html) and in particular the [note in the "Variables"](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables) section:

> **Note:** CMake reserves identifiers that:
>
> - begin with `CMAKE_` (upper-, lower-, or mixed-case), or
> - begin with `_CMAKE_` (upper-, lower-, or mixed-case), or
> - begin with `_` followed by the name of any [`CMake Command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html#manual:cmake-commands(7)).

Answer (score 0):

The general approach to finding this info is to just google "`site:cmake.org/cmake/help "reserved"`". That being said, here it is for you served on a platter.

##### For Variable Names

See [the docs on the CMake language- particularly the section on variable names](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables), which states:

> **Note:** CMake reserves identifiers that:
>
> - begin with `CMAKE_` (upper-, lower-, or mixed-case), or
> - begin with `_CMAKE_` (upper-, lower-, or mixed-case), or
> - begin with `_` followed by the name of any [`CMake Command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-commands.7.html).

This also applies to [message contexts](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MESSAGE_CONTEXT.html).

##### For Target Names

See the docs for [the CMP0037 policy](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0037.html), which state:

> Target names reserved by one or more CMake generators are not allowed. Among others these include `all`, `clean`, `help`, and `install`.
>
> Target names associated with optional features, such as `test` and `package`, may also be reserved. CMake 3.10 and below always reserve them. CMake 3.11 and above reserve them only when the corresponding feature is enabled (e.g. by including the [CTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html) or [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html) modules).

Note also that [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) has a feature where an item argument can be "*A `debug`, `optimized`, or `general` keyword immediately followed by another `<item>`.*", in which case,

> The item following such a keyword will be used only for the corresponding build configuration. The `debug` keyword corresponds to the Debug configuration (or to configurations named in the [`DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS.html#prop_gbl:DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS) global property if it is set). The `optimized` keyword corresponds to all other configurations. The `general` keyword corresponds to all configurations, and is purely optional. Higher granularity may be achieved for per-configuration rules by creating and linking to [IMPORTED library targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html). These keywords are interpreted immediately by this command and therefore have no special meaning when produced by a generator expression.

So if you use such a target name, to link to it, you may need to wrap it with a [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) like `$<1:debug>`.

If you want the output file for such a target to use the within-CMake-reserved name, just do so using [the `OUTPUT_NAME` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html).

##### For Exporting Property Names

See the docs for [the `EXPORT_PROPERTIES` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/EXPORT_PROPERTIES.html), which state:

> Properties starting with INTERFACE_ or IMPORTED_ are not allowed as they are reserved for internal CMake use.

You can technically still use such names for your own purposes, but [to quote Ben Boeckel](https://discourse.cmake.org/t/question-about-reserved-cmake-properties/6104/4) (one of the CMake maintainers):

> They’re reserved in that CMake doesn’t worry about “is anyone else using this?” if it wants to make a new property in that namespace.

If you have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)` and want to use something very similar to such a name but still want to play it safe, just prepend an underscore to the name.

##### For File Set Names

See [the docs for the `FILE_SET` argument of the file set signature of `target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html#file-sets), which state:

> The name of the file set to create or add to. It must contain only letters, numbers and underscores. Names starting with a capital letter are reserved for built-in file sets predefined by CMake. The only predefined set names are those matching the acceptable types. All other set names must not start with a capital letter or underscore.

##### For Link Features

See [the docs for the `$<LINK_LIBRARY:feature,library-list>` generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#genex:LINK_LIBRARY), [for the `CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_GROUP_USING_<FEATURE>` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_GROUP_USING_FEATURE.html), and [the `CMAKE_<LANG>_LINK_LIBRARY_USING_<FEATURE>` variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_LINK_LIBRARY_USING_FEATURE.html), which state:

> Feature names are case-sensitive and may only contain letters, numbers and underscores. Feature names defined in all uppercase are reserved for CMake's own built-in features.