# cmake error:"worker_manage.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c++, cmake

I am learning to use cmake for a project with separate folders, I am getting this error:
`worker_manage.h: No such file or directory`
but i included the .h file in main.cpp`#include "worker_manage.h"`
though it can compile successfully, the terminal does not output anything

Here is my file tree :

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── main.cpp
├── include
│   └── worker_manage.h
├── lib
├── bin
├── build
├── src
├── ├── worker_manage.cpp
    └── CMakeLists.txt
```

Here is my src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
aux_source_directory(. SRC)

add_library(test SHARED ${SRC})
message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR:{PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(main VERSION 1.0)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_compile_options(-Wall -O2)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

aux_source_directory(. ALL_CPP)
message("ALL_CPP: ${ALL_CPP}")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${ALL_CPP})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC test)
```

the output of `message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")` is `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: F:/codes/c++`, which includes the top level CMakeLists.txt. the output of `message("ALL_CPP: ${ALL_CPP}")` is `ALL_CPP: ./main.cpp`

when i change CMakeLists.txt like this, the terminal can output what i want, but i don't know why

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(main VERSION 1.0)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)

add_compile_options(-Wall -O2)

add_subdirectory(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

# aux_source_directory(. ALL_CPP)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp src/worker_manage.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC test)
```

the header file of main.cpp is `#include <iostream> #include "worker_manage.h"`
the header file of worker_manage.cpp is `#include "worker_manage.h"`

Comment: `{PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` in `src/CMakeLists.txt` is `src` and it doesn't contain `include`.

Comment: Try to add after `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ...)` the following: `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)`

Comment: @273K really? their `src/CMakeLists.txt` doesn't contain a call to `project()` though... so I'd have though the project context would still be referring to the directory scope of the `CMakeLists.txt` file's `project` call... joe qiu, could you please show us the output of `message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")` when put in your `src/CMakeLists.txt` file? Please also show the output of `message("ALL_CPP: ${ALL_CPP}")` when placed in your top-level CMakeLists.txt file after the `aux_source_directory` call.

Comment: See what I've written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76068168/11107541. the target name "test" is reserved for CMake 3.10 and below. What if you rename your "test" target to a name that isn't reserved?